# std:find() for sorted vs unsorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

Consider two integer vectors `v1` and `v2`, where `v1` is sorted and `v2` is not sorted. What would be the time complexities to search for an element in these two vectors using `find()`?

Comment: You can look it up, for instance [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) performs [*linear search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), i.e., it goes element by element until it finds the value it's looking for. It is linear regardless of whether or not the collection is sorted.

If you have a sorted vector, you may want to consider performing [*binary search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) with [`std::lower_bound()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) instead. This will be logarithmic in the size of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of `std::find` will always be linear O(n), because it has no knowledge of the `std::vector`. It must consider vector as non-sorted and perform linear search over all elements.

However, real-time may depend on circumstances. Sorting may help because `std::find` can end up sooner. It depends on what you are looking for. Let's say you are looking for `2` in a non-sorted array `(5,1,3,4,2)` - you have to compare all elements. But for sorted `(1,2,3,4,5)` - you compare only two elements and find the `2`.